# Когда лучше всего использовать классы "Сервисы", а когда логику лучше помещать в сам класс?

Tags: архитектура, любой-язык

Как правило, классы сервисы- это таке классы, которые не имеют состояния.

Т.е передаешь им что-то, а в ответ они тебе выплевывают чего-то.

Так вот, я часто вижу то, что какие-то методы можно было поместить в класс рядом с данными, а не выносить это в отдельный сервис.

Так вот, когда это оправдано?

Например, сейчас я наблюдаю сервис, который возвращает некий сложный объект.

Что бы получить какие-то интересующие себя данные, без ручных итераций по внутренним коллекциям, я должен передать конкрутному методу сервиса этот объект и на это он вернет мне результат.

Хотя... по моему, что мешает этот метод дать конкретному экземпляру?

Единственный, наверное, + - это отделить данные от реализации и как следствие, можно не возиться с наследованием.

Comment: В тегах стоит `любой-язык`, но такое ощущение, что это вопрос про "безнес-логику" на java / c#.

Answer (score 6):

**Service** – это Java класс, который предоставляет с себя основную (Бизнес-Логику). 
В основном сервис использует готовые `DAO/Repositories` или же другие сервисы, для того чтобы предоставить конечные данные для пользовательского интерфейса.

Как гласит **Принцип единственной ответственности (Single Responsibility Principle)**:

> ***Один класс должен решать только какую-то одну задачу.*** Он может иметь несколько методов, но они должны использоваться лишь для решения
>   общей задачи. Все методы и свойства должны служить одной цели. Если
>   класс имеет несколько назначений, его нужно разделить на отдельные
>   классы.

Данный подход проектирования кажется не совсем логичный в небольших приложениях, но очень важен при проектировании больших. А так же, так как мы являемся инженерами, мы и в перспективе планируем, чтобы нашим кодом пользовались другие программисты, то должны оставлять возможность для безболезненного расширения функционала приложения.

Answer (score 3):

Такой подход используется в принципе единой ответственности. Например, у нас есть объект письма `Message`, и мы хотим его отправить. Можно реализовать метод `send()` в самом письме, а можно написать сервис `MailService` с методом `send(Message msg)`. Первый случай с точки зрения SOLID будет не верным, так как письмо не может отправить само себя, для этого есть служба (мы просим службу отправить письмо, а служба уже займется доставкой согласно каким-то своим внутренним правилам).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь *очень* много примеров, но я постараюсь разобрать некоторые из них:

#### Интерфейсы (и классы их реализующие)

Да-да-да, я знаю, что "интерфейс вообще" это не "класс вообще" (привет С++), но в чём разница м-ду абстрактным классом и интерфейсом? Абстрактный класс может содержать поля, т. е. состояние, а интерфейс (по крайней мере "чистый") – *только* поведение (его декларацию, которую потом реализует класс... реализатор?).

```cs
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    int someField; // compile error

    void DoSmth(); // no error
}
```

#### XXX-Helpers/Services

Классы вида `SomeHelpers` или `SomeServices`. Тут ничего лишнего:

```cs
public static class SomeServices
{
    public static void Check(this SomeEnum @enum)
    {
        const SomeEnum maxEnum = SomeEnum.SomeMaxValue;

        if (@enum < 0 || @enum > maxEnum)
            throw /*...*/;
    }
}
```

Разве что добавлю по поводу разницы м-ду их именами, как её вижу *я*: `SomeHelpers` - `internal class`, `SomeServices` - `public class`. Опять же, могут быть *исключения*, но я их встречал несколько раз, например:

```cs
public static class DoubleHelpers
{
    public static int Compare(double a, double b);
    public static bool IsZero(double value);
    // ...
}
```

#### ISomeFactory

Интерфейс `ISomeFactory`:

```cs
public interface ISomeFactory
{
    ISomeClass CreateSomeClass(/*some args*/);
}
```

#### ISomeProvider

Интерфейс `ISomeProvider`:

```cs
public interface ISomeProvider
{
    ISomeClass GetObject(/*some args*/);
    // or ISomeClass ProvideObject(/*some args*/);
}
```

Тут от экземпляра класса `SomeObject`. Здесь `ISomeProvider` может быть `IServiceProvider`, а `ISomeObject` – `ISomeService`. Теперь провайдер может возвращать не только объекты, но и сервисы... Ну или даже так:

```cs
public interface IFooProvider
{
    IBarProvider GetProvider();
}
public interface IBarProvider
{
    IBazProvier GetProvider();
}
// ...
// ...
```

#### Формальные "сервисы"

Если мы хотим назвать класс, например, как "служба доставки", то мы его назовём как `DeliveryService`. Здесь "сервис" формальный – это нужно иметь ввиду.

---

Сами по себе сервисы "бесплодны" и могут нести роль:

- Реализуемого контейнера деклараций методов
- Не наследуемого контейнера реализаций методов
- Получателя других объектов (или даже сервисов или других провайдеров)

> Например, сейчас я наблюдаю сервис, который возвращает некий сложный объект.

Вы наблюдаете сервис, реализующий интерфейс провайдера.

---

Пару слов о самих провайдерах. Провайдер, как сперва может показаться, это фабрика, но не совсем. Провайдер отличается от фабрики тем, что объект типа `CreateByFactory` можно создать *только* через фабрику, а объект типа `ProvideByProvider` вы можете *предоставить*, т. е. не только создавать, но и, например, возвращать из кэша, а так же, что самое главное, объект типа `ProvideByProvider` *обязан* мочь быть воссозданным *без* использования провайдеров. Это важно если не хотите недопонимания и открытой ошибки в коде. Ещё раз, фабрика создаёт и не может быть кастомной, провайдер предоставляет и может быть кастомным.

---

Вообще, сервисы целенаправленно и зачастую используются в данных случаях (первое, что мне в голову пришло). Нет смысла просто так брать и создавать класс-сервис, чтоб "полей не было". Например, класс `RandomHelpers`:

```cs
public static class RandomHelpers
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static readonly Random random = new Random();

    public static string[] GenerateStrings(int minCount, int maxCount, int minLength, int maxLength, bool usePrintableCharsOnly = true);
}
```

Здесь статический для потоков `random` - отличный инструмент рефакторинга, позволяющий 1 строчкой не писать код с синхронизацией и, тем самым, оптимизировать run-time, хотя мы и немного (я б сказал *вообще* не) просели в памяти. И вроде статический класс-сервис, но со состоянием... Серьёзно? Эти (в худшем реальном случае, наверно, за историю) съедят 100 байт, не больше. Не нужно экономить, если не просят. Так же стоит сказать, что сервис зачастую – это просто классификация (мол, все классы "без полей" - сервисы).

---

```
                 +-------------------+---------------+
                 | Абстракция        | Реализация    |
+----------------+-------------------+---------------+
| Есть состояние | Абстрактный класс | Обычный класс |
+----------------+-------------------+---------------+
| Нет состояния  | Интерфейс         | Класс-сервис  |
+----------------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Понятие *сервис* несколько противоречиво в мире ООП, поэтому с ним и возникают такие сложности.

В учебнике C++ Бьярна Страуструпа написано, что ООП держится на трёх китах, один из которых это инкапсуляция. Данные и методы надо держать вместе.

Общее правило такого: если методу нужны данные из класса, поместите этот метод прямо в класс.

И этот подход работает хорошо до тех пор, пока методу нужны данные одного класса. А если двух?

На этот вопрос нет общего ответа. Иногда новый код размещают в первом классе, иногда во втором, а иногда — в новом третьем классе.

При принятии решения играют роль вот какие факторы:

1. **Согласованность**. Удобно, если в каждом случае вы принимаете похожие архитектурные решения. Программистам, которые работают над кодом, проще будет его понимать, если в коде прослеживаются закономерности. Если вы решите размещать код в каком-то из двух (трёх, пяти) классов, как это повлияет на остальной код. Не придётся ли вам в других местах вносить правки, чтобы решение оставалось согласованным.
2. **Краткость**. У начинающих архитекторов есть проблема с простыми решениями. Они могут придумать что-то такое, что заставит всю команду писать десятки «лишних» строк кода. Иногда эту штуку называют monkey code, иногда boilerplate. Как его не называй, но это хороший индикатор, что решение не самое хорошее.
3. **Солидность**. Обычно стоит прогнать решение на соответствие принципам SOLID. Метод может быть *лишним* в классе и нарушать Single Responsibility. Или он потребует постоянного дописывания уже готового кода, что нарушит принцип Open/Closed.

В общем и целом, когда стоит создавать службу и выносить методы туда? Когда речь идёт о *процедуре* или *бизнес-процессе*. Скажем, заказ проходит по стадиям (создан, сформирован, оплачен, собран, отправлен, доставлен). Конечно, у заказа есть его *состояние*, которое должно быть инкапсулировано внутри класса `Заказ`.

Но на каждом этапе нужно проводить большое количество проверок с объектами, которые не являются частью заказа: описания товаров, остатки на складе, промо-акции, скидки и многое другое. Всё это удобно вынести в отдельную службу, откуда и вызывать в нужный момент метод изменения состояния заказа.

Про вас случай трудно сказать, не видя кода, и не зная архитектурных ценностей, которые положены в основу проекта. Прежде, чем переносить метод в класс, я бы посмотрел на размер класса. В языках типа Java/C#/C++ размер в 300-400 строк, это мой личный максимум. Ничем не подтвержу и случаи разные бывают, тут всё субъективно.

Второе, я бы посмотрел на другие классы-сущности, которые нужны в работе метода (в параметрах, в коде, в выходном значении). Нормально, если там либо примитивные типы, либо классы, которые называют *объекты-значения*. Точки из координат `x` и `y`, цвета из компонентов `red`, `green`, `blue`. Если же там полноценные сущности, то, пожалуй, стоит оставить метод в службе.

Answer (score 1):

Сервисы с бизнес-логикой и "доменные" сущности без поведения - это в терминологии Фаулера [анемичная модель предметной области](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). Такая реализация тяготеет к процедурному программированию и из ООП не используются его сильные стороны, хотя формально объектная ориентированность присутствует. Тут рекомендую читать вышеприведенную статью об анемичной модели, там все хорошо написано.

Противоположность ей это когда в сервисах нет бизнес логики вообще, а все находится собственно в модели. Такой подход называется rich domain model. Тут слой сервисов не содержит бизнес-логику, является довольно тонким и служит для координации (упрощенно он читает модели из репозитория запускает на них бизнес операции и потом сохраняет результат в репозиторий, т.е. его роль - координирующая).

Поиск по гуглу `anemic vs rich domain model` дает очень много информации, и существует консенсус, что анемичная модель - антипаттерн, в основном потому что применяется очень часто, гораздо чаще, чем должна бы. Смотрите несколько неплохих статей на эту тему:

- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html
- https://amido.com/blog/anaemic-domain-model-vs-rich-domain-model/
- https://blog.pragmatists.com/domain-driven-design-vs-anemic-model-how-do-they-differ-ffdee9371a86
- https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2019/10/ddd-vs-anemic-domain-models/

Answer (score 0):

Все методы класса должны описывать только поведение объекта, в них могут изменяться состояния объекта, со своими внутренними проверками и т.д.

Для действя над объектом этого класса разумно применять сервисный класс, (кстати, этот класс так же должен так отвечать SRP, иначе он может разрастись до супер-класса в библиотеку сервис-методов)

Конкретно, по вопросу:

> сейчас я наблюдаю сервис, который возвращает некий сложный объект

Правильнее получать этот сложный объект из сервиса, а не из объекта-источника данных, так как если исходный объект выполняет какую-то задачу и дополнительно создает (возвращает) какой-то другой объект, то здесь нарушен SRP.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте паттерн "Стратегия". Для чего он нужен, и как реализовывается. Так вот сервис от слова служить. То есть принимает команды и выполняет их, тут схожесть с интерфейсами и их задачами, а не классами. У нас есть протокол которого нужно придерживаться, а кто и как его будет реализовывать, создатель протокола не может знать заблаговременно.